# visual studio complains that variable is not declared

Tags: javascript, asp.net, code-behind

I have an aspx page with the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> var dataPoints = '<%= dataPoints %>'; </script>
```

I populate this variable in code as such:

```
Dim dataPoints = objStringBuilder.ToString()
Context.Response.AppendHeader("dataPoints", dataPoints)
```

I populate the `dataPoints` variable from the code behind.  However, all of a sudden visual studio keeps telling me `Name 'dataPoints' is not declared` **in the aspx file** and no longer builds.  It is referring to `'<%= dataPoints %>'` directive which allows the code behind to pass data to the javascript variable.  This works in production, but my development environment is now complaining.  It does not matter what I name it either, so having the same name as the javascript variable is not the problem.

Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: How do you declare .NET `dataPoints` variable?

Comment: It's just as the code sample shows.  This line is identical to the production version.  In fact the whole page is exactly the same as far as I can tell.  Works in production not in dev.

Comment: How do you declare the variable in vb code behind?

Comment: Seems like an accessibility problem either **dataPoints** should be protected or public

Comment: I fail to see how this code possibly works. You are *not* declaring anything in in your code above. `<%=foo %>` translates to `Reponse.Write(the_value_of_foo)`. Your code behind is adding an (custom) HTTP header

Answer (score 0):

Possible reasons:

- `CodeBehind` property is not set properly for the ASP.NET page
- The code behind file is not compiled
- The dll which contains the code behind code is not deployed to the `bin` folder

Comment: It's just a variable, not a class.  Again this works in the prod environment, just not in dev.

Comment: The value gets set in the code behind.  I use the data with javascript.  This is just a way for the code behind to talk to the javascript.

Comment: to be clear, I use the statement Context.Response.AppendHeader("dataPoints", dataPoints) in the vb code.  This populates the variable in javascript with my desired data.

Comment: The variable '<%= dataPoints %>' is actually replaced with the data filled from the code behind.

Comment: But, it's now throwing a compile error.  This is the reason I have posted the question.

Comment: Think of '<%= dataPoints %>' as a placeholder.  It's not really a variable, so the compile error is really confusing!

Comment: Actually the tag '<%= dataPoints %>' IS the declaration!  That's why it is surrounded with directive statement tags.  Again. this does actually work in the prod environment - I am not making that up.  It just started complaining recently and only in dev.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but there's something else going on here.